# Modify Express js response to avoid some specific values

Tags: node.js, string, typescript, express, replace

I have an Express app which returns big [decimal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js/v/3.0.0) numbers (their textual representations) in response.

```
const app = express();
app.use('api_url', router); 

router.route('')
    .all(bodyParser.json())
    .all(function (req, res, next) {...})
.post((req, res) => {
    const response: CalcResponse = this.myService.getResponse(req);
    res.status(200).send(response);
});
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The problem is that decimal numbers can be `Infinity` or `NaN`. I want to avoid such values in a response and replace them with empty strings. The `response` has `CalcResponse` type which is a `TypeScript` class. Is there any way to replace the values in the middleware?

Something like that:

```
app.use((response) => response.replace(/(Infinity|NaN)/g, ''));
```

Comment: which part of the code generates the response? what's inside of that router? can you provide us with some more code?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I added more details. Some service there generates a response which is JS object.

Comment: what's the type of `const response`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski probably a number in its textual form, or an object containing numbers in a textual form

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I have a TypeScript class (let's say) CalcResponse. It contains some other fields. 
response has CalcResponse type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using javascripts built in function `isFinite` ?

```js
  var a = isFinite(123)
  var b = isFinite(-1.23)
  var c = isFinite(5-2)
  var d = isFinite(0)
  var e = isFinite(NaN)
  var f = isFinite(Infinity)

console.log({a,b,c,d,e,f})
```

Since i don't know what the type of the response from the service of yours is (number or string representation of a number) i'll provide 2 solutions.

For number:

```
res.status(200).send(isFinite(response) ? response : "")
```

For string solution you suggested yourself:

```
res.status(200).send(response.replace(/(Infinity|NaN)/g, ''))
```

If you are not sure of the type yourself, you can simplify the solution to treat all of them like strings

```
res.status(200).send(response.toString().replace(/(Infinity|NaN)/g, ''))
```

Normally `JSON.stringify` replaces `NaN` and `Infinity` values with nulls, so i'd suggest writing own replacer function to change them to empty strings like in example bellow

```js
const data = {a: Infinity, b: NaN, c: 1, d: "test"}
function replacer(key, val){ 
  if (typeof val === "number" && !isFinite(val)) return ""
  return val;
}

const stringified = JSON.stringify(data, replacer);

console.log(stringified)
```

Even if they are in fact strings like `"Infinity"` or `"NaN"` instead, you can still use replacer function to achieve similar results

```js
const data = {a: "Infinity", b: "NaN", c: 1, d: "test"}
function replacer(key, val){ 
  if (val === "Infinity" || val === "NaN") return ""
  return val;
}

const stringified = JSON.stringify(data, replacer);

console.log(stringified)
```

Comment: Does `isFinite()` support numbers in textual form (`string`)? Otherwise, it doesn't answer his question

Comment: he says that the response would be textual, which is required by http message standard, even if you were to call `res.send(1)` in express the request to that endpoint would return the `"1"` as such i asked in the comment about the part that's actually generating the numbers to know if provided solution applies

Comment: I have a big JS object with a lot of fields which is a result of big calculations. If I will check every calculation with isFinite() it will cause a lot additions in code.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I am sorry. I didn't mentioned that I use TypeScript. 
So response has custom class Type `CalcResponse`.

Comment: what exactly is this custom class? Also how do you expect to conditionally change the value without checking the condition?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Thank you. 
I just can use `res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response).replace(...)` as you suggested. It helped me

Comment: hey i updated my answer passing replacer function as stringify argument rather than manually replacing those after stringify

Comment: it probably does not make any difference in your case, but it's a good programming practice and it will not replace those values in case of them being inside of string like `"something Infinity something"` which may be desirable